# Install an image of Windows7(with some installed programs) through LAN, without Windows PE limitations, is it possible?

Tags: windows-7, windows-pe

Im trying to install windows7 (with some basic programs) on many PCs throught LAN, I have read that I can do it via PXE tool, like AOEMI Backupper PXE boot tool, or Serva PXE, but both ways uses Windows PE, and I have read here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx that a Windows PE Installation is different that a normal Windows Install, eg "Windows PE automatically stops running the shell and reboots after 72 hours of continuous use. This time period is not configurable". Could please somebody confirm that, or comment about its experience with Windows PE installed OS?

I would like these PCs to be running 24/7 using postgresql database (SELECT and INSERT) in that LAN, use skype and other IM basic tools. I guess a Windows PE installation couldn't work for that purpose, since it will automatically restart? Right now I think I will have to clone many times, the hard drive where the Windows7 (and the programs) are placed. Isn't there any other alternative that could spare me that task? is there a way to mount an image of a fully operative windows7 (with some programs already installed) throught LAN (that is not Windows PE). Thanks Advanced.

Comment: http://kentonsprojects.blogspot.sg/2011/12/lan-party-house-technical-design-and.html old but worth a read. In theory you basically need to do a PXE boot, and use iscsi for the drives

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PE will just be the way you get your computers to the image of the reference machine.  It will only need to run for a small amount of time.

Boot PE -- Grab Image -- Computers Install Windows7.

[Technet Preparing an image using sysprep and imagex](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/preparing-an-image-using-sysprep-and-imagex.aspx)

[Basic Windows 7 Deployment for IT Professionals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd349348(v=ws.10).aspx)

Hope that helps.

Comment: What about the windows PE limitations???  I have read here https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc766093(v=ws.10).aspx that a Windows PE Installation is different that a normal Windows Install, eg "Windows PE automatically stops running the shell and reboots after 72 hours of continuous use. This time period is not configurable".???

Comment: The PE Installation is just a 'gateway' to get the real Windows 7 install going.  After the first reboot of the "real" Windows 7 Install you won't be in PE anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Lets try to clarify a couple of things:

1) To install Windows means to deliver the install components to the target hard disk and reboot your target PC (from its HDD) and enjoy a newly installed Windows OS.

2) To boot a "live" version of Windows can be done when booting PE

The MS PXE install process for installing Vista and up uses an initial PE executive booted into ram and it is this executive the one that is on charge of the initial stages of the install procedure. a regular install takes today 20 minutes or so then the limitations of windows PE will never affect any normal install.

Now if you want to use a PE executive as a regular OS then you will be in trouble because MS has added "limitations" to PE just to avoid users using PE for other use different than installs/recovery tool/and the like.

Then if you want to run a "live" version of Windows (i.e. for a cybercafe) (thing that MS doesn't like) then forget about PE, if you want to install Windows OSs the PE "is the way" and there's no any limitation affecting this use.